# Join two lines with awk or sed

Tags: macos, bash, sed, awk

If I have:

```
foo  
bar
```

..and I'd like to awk/sed this to:

```
foo-bar
```

..what's the syntax?

I'm trying to use System Profiler on OS X 10.6.x:

```
system_profiler SPMemoryDataType | awk '/Type/ {print $2} /Speed/ {print $2}'
```

to output type-speed (ie DDR-1067).  Haven't figured out how to do this using `print` or `printf` yet, might try to just `grep` instead..

Answer (score 6):

#### With `tr`:

```
tr '\n' '-'
```

Would that be enough? This replaces every newline with a comma.

---

#### With `sed`:

A prettier solution using `sed`:

```
sed -e N -e 's/\n/-/'
```

The `N` appends the newline to the pattern space according to the manpage:

> `[2addr]N`
>
> Append the next line of input to the pattern space, using an embedded newline character to separate the appended material from the original
>                contents.  Note that the current line number changes.

---

#### With `bash`

Actually, bash can do what `tr` can do. Just for completeness:

```
while read l; do echo -n "$l-"; done
```

---

Here's a similar question on Stack Overflow: [SED: How can I replace a newline (\n)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n)

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'BEGIN {ORS="-"} {print}'
```

Joins your data. What's inside the begin statement happens prior to reading the data. Here we define that the output record separator is -. `Print` prints the data.